# ts class is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have the main module like this

```
import { filequeue, utils } from "./helpers/";
export let u: utils = new utils();
export let queue: filequeue = new filequeue();
```

in helpers folder there is the index.ts like this

```
export * from "./utils.helpers";
export * from "./filequeue.helpers";
```

when I run the main module, filequeue gives me this error

> filequeue is not a constructor

If I change to this

```
import { filequeue } from "./helpers/filequeue.helpers";
import { utils } from "./helpers/utils.helpers";
```

it works, why?

FYI, this is the code in the filequeue

```
export class filequeue {
  public name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `new filequeue()` and that the bottom code is the current implementation of the `filequeue` class?
The error you are getting is not an TypeScript error, but one that pops up in JavaScript runtime. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor for more on this.